# static array of trait objects

Tags: rust, static, traits

Is it possible to define static array of trait objects:

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

trait Tr {}

struct A {}
impl Tr for A {}

struct B {}
impl Tr for B {}

lazy_static! {
    static ref ARR: [Box<dyn Tr>;2] = [Box::new(A {}), Box::new(B {})];
    // error[E0277]: `(dyn Tr + 'static)` cannot be shared between threads safely
}
```

Instead of having one `_arr` per each `Test` instance:

```rust
struct Test {
    arr: [Box<dyn Tr>; 2],
}

impl Default for Test {
    fn default() -> Test {
        Test {
            arr: [Box::new(A {}), Box::new(B {})],
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `Box<dyn Tr + Sync>`:

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

trait Tr {}

struct A {}
impl Tr for A {}

struct B {}
impl Tr for B {}

lazy_static! {
    static ref ARR: [Box<dyn Tr + Sync>; 2] = [Box::new(A {}), Box::new(B {})];
}
```

From the documentation of [`Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sync.html):

> Types for which it is safe to share references between threads.