# How to create a static array of objects that implement a common trait?

Tags: arrays, rust, static, traits

I am trying to create a static array of objects that implement a common trait. All these structs and their sizes are known at compile time. But when accessing a field defined on the struct the compiler tells me that the field is not on the type.

```
fn main() {
    for &thing in ALL_THINGS {
        println!("{}", thing.name)
    }
}
trait Thing: Sync { }

struct SpecificThing { 
    name: &'static str
}
impl Thing for SpecificThing { }

static ALL_THINGS: &'static [&dyn Thing] = &[&SpecificThing {name: "test"}];
```

---

```
error[E0609]: no field `name` on type `&dyn Thing`
 --> src/main.rs:3:30
  |
3 |         println!("{}", thing.name)
  |                              ^^^^
```

Example:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=28a29e98cadf97edb8d4ec61703e8959

The questions [static array of trait objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59679968/static-array-of-trait-objects), [Create vector of objects implementing a trait in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134158/create-vector-of-objects-implementing-a-trait-in-rust), [Can I have a static borrowed reference to a trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667717/can-i-have-a-static-borrowed-reference-to-a-trait-object) or [Vector of objects belonging to a trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818082/vector-of-objects-belonging-to-a-trait) doesn't help with explaining why this happens or how to resolve it.

Please what am I doing wrong here? Is there a better method to solve this task that I have not found yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define `&dyn Thing`, you erase all the information about specific data type. That means you can't access fields of dinamically dispatched objects.

Just imagine that you have two different structs in `ALL_THINGS`:

```
struct SpecificThing { 
    name: &'static str
}
struct SpecificAnotherThing { 
    no_name: &'static str
}

static ALL_THINGS: &'static [&dyn Thing] = &[&SpecificThing {name: "test"}, &SpecificAnotherThing { no_name: "" }];
```

You can't access `name` field because trait `Thing` know nothing about concrete types it implemented for. Therefore you can't access it's fields directly.

If you really need it, you should define a method in `Thing` trait which will return value you need:

```rust
trait Thing: Sync {
   fn name(&self) -> &str;
}
// ...
// ...
impl Thing for SpecificThing {
   fn name(&self) -> &str {
       self.name
   }
}
```

Or you can use static dispatching and algebraic data types (`enum`).

Answer (score 1):

You can't access `SpecificThing.name` from a `&dyn Thing` since not all `Things` have a `name` field (ignoring the fact that traits don't have fields).

Your use of `dyn Thing` suggests you have a set of objects (structs/enums) that have some things in common. All these commonalities must be present in `Thing` for you to access them. For example, if a name is a common thing, you could add a function that gets the name:

```
fn main() {
    for &thing in ALL_THINGS {
        println!("{}", thing.get_name())
    }
}
trait Thing: Sync { 
    fn get_name(&self) -> &'static str;
}

struct SpecificThing { 
    name: &'static str
}
impl Thing for SpecificThing {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &'static str {
        self.name
    }
    
}

static ALL_THINGS: &'static [&dyn Thing] = &[&SpecificThing {name: "test"}];
```